# Receiving QChart or QChartView object from QML via signal

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I need an access to ChartView item declared in *.qml.

I've tried to pass it (**ChartView { id: scopeViewTop}**) from QML to C++ via signal

main.qml:

```
onClick: {core.rcvQChart(mainForm.rootRect.mainSplitView.chartsNControls.
                                   chartsSplitView.scopeViewTop}
```

core.h:

```
public slots:
    void rcvQChart(QtCharts::QChartView *chartObj);
```

core.cpp:

```
void Core::rcvQChart(QtCharts::QChartView *chartObj){
    qDebug() << "    rcvQChart() called";
    chartObj->hide();
}
```

This results in a segfault if I use any method on received object.

What is the proper way to access an object with specific id created in QML from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to send/receive QML item as a QObject, not as a QChartView:

```
void Core::rcvQChart(QObject *chartObj){
    qDebug() << "received: " << chartObj;
    qDebug() << "visible ? " << chartObj->property("visible");
    chartObj->setProperty("visible", "false");
    qDebug() << "visible ? " << chartObj->property("visible");
}
```

Output:

```
received:  ScopeViewTop_QMLTYPE_15(0x2735d20, name = "chartViewTop")
visible ?  QVariant(bool, true)
visible ?  QVariant(bool, false)
```